# Hibernate output chinese character grabbled in remote server

Tags: java, linux, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I make a application interface in springmvc and using @Pathvariable to accept users' input, here is the snippet of my @Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFirst/{var}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getFirst(@PathVariable String var){
    String fr = "select * from Food f where f.resname like '%" + var + "%'";
    List<Site> siteList = siteService.findBySQL(fr);
    Site first = siteList.get(0);
    return first.getSrc();
}
```

Here i deploy my application in local tomcat server and type url `http://localhost:8080/springmvc/getFirst/鸡排` and got result normally.

but while i deploy the application to the remote tomcat server and type the same parameter `http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/springmvc/getFirst/鸡排` and got below exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
cn.crabime.StudentController.getFirst(StudentController.java:99)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cn.crabime.filter.FoodFilter.doFilter(FoodFilter.java:22)
```

First, I think maybe it's the issue of chinese character encoding, but i have already defined a FoodFilter to intercept input url and found chinese character has already been encoded.

Second, I thought it's hibernate dealing with chinese character problem, but you can see local server works normal, so it should not be. but i notice the most impressive place, while using local server, IntelliJ idea output sql sentence generated by hibernate normally, and chinese character didn't grabbed, but in remote server like this:

```
    当前用户请求的url为http://139.129.229.46:8080/springmvc/getFirst/%E9%B8%A1%E6%8E%92
last slice is :鸡排
Hibernate: select * from Food f where f.resname like '%é¸¡æ%'
```

But i don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,this question has resolved by myself, [here is an article about tomcat dealing with chinese character garbled issue](http://www.codeweblog.com/jboss-seam-mysql-chinese-garbled-summary-of-4-steps/).Just because of the default character encoding of tomcat is iso-8859-1, such encoding style would make chinese character garbled, so go to remote tomcat server conf folder and change such snippet:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
            maxThreads="2000"
            minSpareThreads="100"
            maxSpareThreads="1000"
            acceptCount="1000"
            URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

**Attention**:URIEncoding must be specified as 'UTF-8'.